# WebDriver window resize | Chrome Driver 2.28 | Chrome 57

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I have used set position to change the browser window size in my webdriver automation.
When I run the code with Chrome driver 2.28, it throws below exception

```
**Exception starting line:**

driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(pos_x, pos_y));


**Trace:**

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension**


from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  **(Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520** (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.21 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'


System info: host: 'TESTVM', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir21364_25403}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, **version=57.0.2987.110**, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 2af85eb51f31434f8df972a737b82bd4
```

The actual use case is to open multiple Chrome windows and make all the windows to be in focus. Now, I'm not able to resize the window.

Final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        final String adminToolURL =
            "http://www.google.com";
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

```
    final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(500, 600));

    driver.get(adminToolURL);
    driver.getWindowHandles();
    final String adminToolHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    int x = 0, y = 30;
    String window = "win";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        window = window + String.valueOf(i);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("window.open('https://www.google.com','"
            + window + "',height=" + x + ",width=" + y + ");");
        final String handle = driver.getWindowHandle();

        driver.switchTo().window(handle.toString());
        // driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(pos_x, pos_y));
        pos_x = pos_x + 180;
        if ((i % 7) == 0) {
            pos_y = pos_y + 160;
            pos_x = 0;
        }
        x += 30;
        y += 40;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        final Set<String> customerWindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
        customerWindow.removeAll(customerWindow);
        driver.switchTo().window(adminToolHandle);
    }
    Thread.sleep(600000);
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.

The solution turned out to be very simple - you need to start ChromeDriver with options.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
_driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The code is on C#. On jave it must be almost the same.

So this is a workaround how you can maximize the browser without getting the error.